# Alternative to SSH and SNMP for remotely gathering metrics

Tags: remote, remote-management, protocols

Does anyone know of alternative protocols for gathering metrics remotely from Linux servers other than SSH and SNMP? We are looking to support as much of the Linux ecosystem as possible including very old distributions so the protocol needs to be broadly available.

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Export a script to the monitored systems that produces the stats you want on a pre-selected random TCP port, when you connect to the port. Protocols? It's up to you. When I did similar for a multinational company, I defined my own protocol, with multiple commands and updates pushable to the clients. I used 32-bit encryption/obfuscation to avoid export difficulties.

Comment: Start by adding precision "very old distributions"? How old? What metrics do you want to collect?

Comment: It would help to understand why SNMP (for example) isn't acceptable